# Want to get subdirectories in a directory in a list

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

I am using ubuntu 16.04 . On my machine i am working in the Downloads directory . I have a directory called pictures within downloads, within pictures i have 2 more folders with pictures in them.

Directory is as follows

~/Downloads/pictures/folder1

~/Downloads/pictures/folder2

I want to get a list of the directory like

```
directories = ['home/user/Downloads/pictures/folder1','home/user/Downloads/pictures/folder2']
```

I am using the following code

```
import os

path = '~/Downloads/pictures'

folders = []

# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for folder in d:
        folders.append(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(r, folder)))

for z in folders:
    print(z)
```

This works perfectly fine in windows, but when i run on ubuntu the folders folder in empty with length 0 .
How do i get the **'folders'** folder to fill up with the directories i want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get directories from a path, you should first build your path correctly (look at the use of `expanduser` to get the user path), then look for directories (note the use of list comprehension):

```
import os
from os.path import expanduser

usrdir = expanduser("~")
path = usrdir+'/Downloads/pictures'

folders = [d[0] for d in os.walk(path)]
```

Comment: still not getting anything. When i try ```print(len(folders))``` i get 0

Comment: it is, the code didn't work even when i edited the path to

`path = '~/Downloads' `
   the folders list was still empty

Comment: I see. Changing the path to `path = 'home/username/Downloads/pictures'`, where `username` is the name of the user, must work.